# Hibernate Spring Thread Spcific connections

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, jboss, sap-ase

I am developing a web application using Hibernate with Spring 2.5 framework running on Jboss 5.1.I am using hibernateTemplate in spring to perform the hibernate operations.Some part of processing required a multi -threaded approach.So I have implemented multi-threading using TaskPoolExecutor.Now I want each of these threads that are spawned to have a new connection with the database(Sybase ASE).

How can I configure thread specific connections in hibernate?

Thanks in Advance!

Cheers,
Dwarak

Answer (score 1):

Use `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession` to access a `Session` (and JDBC connection, in turn) bound to a thread. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#architecture-current-session

Comment: And how would you set the connection in the Session? Using the session's `reconnect` method? This is really not recommended, specially because one should only interface with Hibernate's connection through doWork method. Also, note that `connection()` method is deprecated.

Comment: `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` will be a connected `Session` until you call `Session.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the purpose? If you want to do it for performance reasons, I'd recommend using a connection pooling mechanism and let it manage the connections for you. As you are using JBoss, you can get a managed connection using JNDI. In any case, just remember that you'd need to have one session per thread.